# SQL Query with foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

So I just can't find a good way to make a single query and get what I need. I do have 2 tables.

**1st table**

```
cure
----
code (PK)
name
```

**2nd table**

```
interaction
------------
cure_code1 (FK)
cure_code2 (FK)
interaction
```

I need to get name of the first cure, name of the second cure and the interaction of a single row in the interaction table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What might be tripping you up is that you have to join to the `cure` table twice, once for each foreign key:

```
SELECT
    c1.name AS first_cure,
    c2.name AS second_cure,
    i.interaction
FROM
    interaction i
JOIN
    cure c1 ON i.cure_code1 = c1.code
JOIN
    cure c2 ON i.cure_code2 = c2.code
```

In this query, we join to `cure` twice but give each one its own alias (`c1` or `c2`) so that the columns are ambiguous.

If your application could potentially have `n` cures, then your current table structure won't work. You would need a third table that has an interaction code and a cure code so you can do a many to many mapping.

Comment: lol I tried to do this with a single join, this was easier than I expected, thanks ! and yeah I'm not that stupid, totally understand ur query :D

Comment: why it won't work? application will have n cures, but one cure can react only once to another

Comment: You actually could do it with one join, but you'd need an `OR` for each JOIN constraint, or an IN statement. This way is just cleaner IMO.

Comment: It would work, but it's a bad design to put each potential cure as it's own column. If you had a table with 10 cure columns, most of them would be `NULL`, which is a smell.

Comment: Well u might be right but this is only a school project, for my usage I'd do my best but right now I just wanna finish this one. My lecturer saw my UML diagram and said it's all good. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomek. Fair enough. Something to keep in mind for your future real projects! (Your current design violates one of those normal forms you might have learned about :)).